# generic makefile to create multiple executable using different flags

Tags: makefile

I would like to create a generic Makefile that builds several executables using different compiler flags for each executable without using shell commands.  The executable file name should be composed from the source file and a unique post fixed name.  It should also produce an assembly or preprocessor file per source file if needed.
For the target BIN_BDG_FILES, the "$<" (exercise-1.1.0.c ) is always the first item from the list (exercise-1.1.0.c exercise-1.1.1.c exercise-1.2.0.c exercise-1.2.1.c) as expected.    I tried without success to modify the SRC_FILES using the filter-out function.  My intent was to remove the first item from the list for each Target, so that the first item corresponds to the correct target.  I am not sure this is the correct approach.  Your comments are welcome.

i.e. 
This is my attempt at using built in make constructs.

```
$(BIN_DBG_FILES): $(SRC_FILES)
    $(CC) $(DBG_CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $< -o $@
    echo SRC_FILES := $(filter-out $<, $(SRC_FILES))
```

Makefile

```
SHELL           = bash 
SRC_FILES       = $(wildcard *.c)
BIN_FILES       = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRC_FILES))
BIN_DBG_FILES   = $(patsubst %.c,%-dbg,$(SRC_FILES))
SRC_PRE         = $(patsubst %.c,%-pre,$(SRC_FILES))

CC              = gcc

WARNINGS       := -Wall
CFLAGS          = -O2 -std=c99 $(WARNINGS)
DBG_CFLAGS      = -g -O -std=c99 $(WARNINGS)
PRE_FLAG        = -E
IFLAGS          = -I.

all: $(BIN_FILES) $(BIN_DBG_FILES) MK-BASH

$(BIN_DBG_FILES): $(SRC_FILES)
    $(CC) $(DBG_CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $< -o $@

MK-BASH::
    for src in $(SRC_FILES); do \
            echo $(CC) $(DBG_CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $$src -o $${src%.c}-dbg; \
            $(CC) $(DBG_CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $$src -o $${src%.c}-dbg; \
            $(CC) $(DBG_CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $$src -o $${src%.c}-dbg; \
            $(CC) $(PRE_FLAG) $$src > $${src%.c}-pre; \
    done

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN_FILES) *-dbg *-pre
```

This is the output from executing make command.

This is the output from the target BIN_FILES.

```
gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Wall    exercise-1.1.0.c   -o exercise-1.1.0

gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Wall    exercise-1.1.1.c   -o exercise-1.1.1

gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Wall    exercise-1.2.0.c   -o exercise-1.2.0

gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Wall    exercise-1.2.1.c   -o exercise-1.2.1
```

This is the output from target BIN_DBG_FILES which uses the first source file on the list to build all targets.  It should use the appropriate file (exercise-1.1.1.c) to build each target file (exercise-1.1.1-dbg).

```
gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. **exercise-1.1.0.c** -o exercise-1.1.0-dbg

gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. **exercise-1.1.0.c** -o exercise-1.1.1-dbg

gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. **exercise-1.1.0.c** -o exercise-1.2.0-dbg

gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. **exercise-1.1.0.c** -o exercise-1.2.1-dbg
```

This is the output from the target MK-BASH using shell commands.

```
for src in exercise-1.1.0.c exercise-1.1.1.c exercise-1.2.0.c exercise-1.2.1.c; do \
    echo gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. $src -o ${src%.c}-dbg; \
    gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. $src -o ${src%.c}-dbg; \
    gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. $src -o ${src%.c}-dbg; \
    gcc -E $src > ${src%.c}-pre; \
done
```

output:

```
gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. exercise-1.1.0.c -o exercise-1.1.0-dbg

gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. exercise-1.1.1.c -o exercise-1.1.1-dbg

gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. exercise-1.2.0.c -o exercise-1.2.0-dbg

gcc -g -O -std=c99 -Wall -I. exercise-1.2.1.c -o exercise-1.2.1-dbg
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you explain "the executable file name should be composed from the source file and a unique post fixed name"?

Comment: If there are three C source files, file1.c, file2.c, and file3.c, in the directory with the Makefile file and the executables are compiled with debug option, then the executables could be named file1-dbg, file2-dbg, and file3-dbg, respectively.  That is a filename.c would have an executable name {<filename><postfix-name>}.  In this case if the postfix-name was "-dbg", then example the name is filename-dbg.

Comment: My question is how to write the equivalent target rule for BIN_DBG_FILES so that it produces the same results as the target rule MK-BASH without resorting to using the shell commands.  The target rule output from BIN_BDG_FILES shows targets exercise-1.1.1-dbg, exercise-1.2.0-dbg, and exercise-1.2.1-dbg all use execise-1.1.0.c to create the targets which is not my intent.  The respective targets should use execise-1.1.1.c, execise-1.2.0.c, and execise-1.2.1.c as showed in the target rule output from MK-BASH.

Comment: The issue with the target rule MK-BASH is that it always compiles targets even when the source files are not modified.  If implemented correctly, I am assuming the target rule BIN_BDG_FILES will have the same benefits as the implicit target rules used in BIN_FILES.  That is a target will only be rebuilt if its prerequisite is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pattern rule:

```
DBG: $(BIN_DBG_FILES)

%-dbg: %.c
    @echo $(CC) $(DBG_CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and this is type of solution I wanted for this problem.  Thanks.